# Behaviour of different javascript execution contexts

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a popup say - `alert("Hi Tuhin!");`
What are the basic differences when we use alerts with various methods and events listed below:

1. Directly inside the script tag example `<script type="text/javascript">alert("Hi Tuhin!");</script>`
2. Within `document.addEventListener( "DOMLoaded", function(){alert("Hi Tuhin!");}, false);`
3. Inside `window.onload = function(){ alert("Hi Tuhin!"); }`
4. `$("document").ready( function () { alert("Hi Tuhin!"); });`
5. `<script type="text/javascript"> window.alert("Hi Tuhin!") </script>`

Comment: alert behaves the same in all cases

Comment: Yes you are correct. I searching for answers as when do they load, i.e., loaded on the browser during parsing ? or is it like alert will be shown after entire DOM resources are loaded ?

Comment: sorry, I thought you asked about the behaviour of alert itself

Comment: @Jaromanda X : No, that was not my query.

Comment: interview question? Seems like some off thing to ask.

Comment: You may be interested by the example #8 [here](http://w3c.github.io/html/webappapis.html#dom-alert)

Comment: There are already many well thought out explanations of the differences between these methods

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, this is more of a question of how/when these alerts get fired.

1) This will alert when the `script` is loaded, ergo whenever your code gets that far down.

2) Not too sure which one you're trying to call here, either `document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){})` which is deprecated or `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){})`. The latter, which I assume is the one you meant, will fire as soon as the DOM is loaded without waiting for any CSS/images to finish.

3) `window.onload` will fire after all elements have loaded in the DOM, including images and whatnot.

4) `$("document).ready()` fires similarly to `DOMContentLoaded`, where it will fire as soon as the DOM is loaded.

5) `window.alert()` is pretty similar to using just `alert()`, however calling window.alert() is a good idea if you have a function in your scope called `alert`.