# How to have a CSS animation wait to load after JQuery or Page Loads

Tags: jquery, css

I built an SVG animation that runs using CSS Keyframes. It works great on Desktop, but when it's on a slower mobile device, the animation is almost over when the page loads.

The problem is that I am using CSS (animation-delay: 3s), but the page is taking about 4 seconds to load so that by the time it loads, my animation is already starting. I need the page to fully load and my Jquery to be loaded before the CSS animation starts!

BASICALLY, how do you get a page to FULLY load before the CSS animation-delay property runs, or how to get it to run AFTER your Jquery Document ready is loaded.

Comment: You could remove the class `.foo` you're using to apply the animation to the element `#bar` and use a jQuery function to either: **1-**  add the class `.foo` to element `#bar` or **2-** add the animation property via `.css()` once the page has loaded.

Comment: This is actually what I first did and it worked well. But then on slower devices the Jquery would load before the page was fully ready and I'd have the same problem. So I guess I need some sort of Javascript or JQuery that ACTUALLY waits for every single element to load before firing. Appreciate the comment though.

Comment: Read [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45497385/2159528), for the different possible "ready" events.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few ideas on how to do this.

You could set the animation to load after 5 seconds.

Or, create a light-weight mobile version. Or take out what impacts loading the page loading time. Use min versions.

Edit: try (animation-delay: 5) depending on mobile pixels.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {

}
```

Comment: I've done this but the problem is that every mobile phone loads differently. If I load it too early it messes up. If I load it too late it messes up. I guess I was looking for something that would fire at the same time on both desktop and mobile.

Comment: I have another idea Staveven. Since it is taking awhile to load. I would suggest loading it on your server in a minified version. The reason I am suggesting that is, I ran into the same problem awhile back. What I did was loaded all resources required to display what I needed from my website. It no longer needed to download the resources or fetch it from an external source. So my page speed increased. Also, at the top <head> I had the same problem. I was loading unnecessary resources. Have you tried loading js at the bottom of the page from your server?

Comment: That would have been a good idea too. What I ended up doing is using jquery to add/remove classes to fire the css at the exact intervals. Basically I removed CSS animation delays to avoid waiting on the DOM to finish loading.