# JQuery .load callback is called before .ready callback in loaded script, what is proper way of initialization loaded scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In main document on button click I am loading content of some div with

```
$("#my_div").load(function() {
    alert("Loaded");
});
```

The loaded content is just script

```
<script>
alert("Init outside");
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Init inside");
}
</script>
```

And sequence of alerts is "Init outside", "Loaded", "Init inside".

Am I correct, that it is proper way to initialize loaded script in script body, means where `alert("Init outside")` resides? Not in `.ready()` handler?

Because in my real workflow I am definitely need to initialize script before `.load()` callback is processed. In `.load()` callback I am showing loaded modal,  but before, the modal should initialize itself, i.e. set `on('show.bs.modal')` handler etc.

It's quite strange, that initialization should happen outside `$(document).ready()` handler if I need such sequence, so that's why I am asking.

UPD: The question is not a duplicate, cause it's related more on JQuery-defined sequence of initialization and callbacks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behaviour of different javascript execution contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497238/behaviour-of-different-javascript-execution-contexts)

Comment: The only thing you'd really want in the `$(document).ready()` or `.load()` events are things that reference elements on the page. For example, anything use of a jQuery selector will need to wait for the page to load, so it would either have to be in the `ready` event, or triggered by something after the document loads.

Comment: In my scenario I am definitely need to reference elements in **loaded** content, i.e. set on('show.bs.modal') handler for bootstrap modal, so it seems that .ready is the right place. The only problem that it's called **after** .load() handler where I am showing this modal, so my on('show.bs.modal') handler is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends somewhat on what you're doing in the modal-initialising step, but if there's no asynchronous element to it you shouldn't need to put the initialising code & the code that actually shows it in separate callbacks. If the code blocks are in callbacks for different events, there's ambiguity around which one will run first - you want to know for sure they'll run in order.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    // your init code
  });

  $('#modal').modal('show');
}
```

Binding a callback to the `show.bs.modal` event as you've described is a synchronous action, so the code can be placed in the same block. `.ready()` just waits for elements to be ready (which is all you should need), while `.load()` waits for all content to be loaded, but either will ensure your elements have loaded before their callbacks execute.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Finally I had to trigger "modal:initialization_done" event in loaded dialog, and then show modal on this event occurs.